# The Material ui DatePicker can use like component without dialog?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use the DatePicker in Material UI, and I want it always show in the template, but the default of DatePicker is focused the Textfield and show the Dialog.

Does it possible to show DatePicker without using Dialog and focused Textfield. Let it always show the DatePicker Component at the render show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Solution for the **material-ui v0.x**]**

If I understood you correctly, you want to display `Calendar` component from `DatePicker` without any dialog and input. If that is your case, you can import the inner `Calendar` component like this:

```
import Calendar from 'material-ui/DatePicker/Calendar';
```

and then render, for example:

```
<Calendar 
    autoOk={false}
    cancelLabel={false}
    firstDayOfWeek={1}
    onTouchTapDay={this.handleTouchTapDay}
    mode={'portrait'}
    open={true}
    ref="calendar"
/>
```

There is some other props that is available for `Calendar`, that I hadnt use for this example. You can find them [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v0.x/src/DatePicker/Calendar.js#L24) in the source code of `Calendar`:

Here is what I got after render:

[image]

---

**[Solution for the material-ui 4x]**

In v4 Date pickers came in a separate package, `@material-ui/pickers`

Here is the [documentation](https://v4.mui.com/components/pickers/#material-ui-pickers) on this.

The code is pretty much the same, except that for a new pickers it is required to wrap them with `MuiPickersUtilsProvider`. Here is a simplest example:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, Calendar } from "@material-ui/pickers";

render(
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <Calendar date={new Date()}/>
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-shape-ulfht?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Yes, it is what I want. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that in Material UI v4?

Comment: @Machado Yes, updated answer for v4.

Comment: Nice! I ended up going in a different way, using `@material-ui/pickers` and it worked fine as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible:

```
<div>
  <DatePicker hintText="Portrait Inline Dialog" container="inline" />
</div>
```

### container prop:

> Used to control how the Date Picker will be displayed when the input field is focused. dialog (default) displays the DatePicker as a dialog with a modal. inline displays the DatePicker below the input field (similar to auto complete).

Comment: I mean the DatePicker can show without focused the textfield, Have another solution?

Comment: What Material UI version is this?