# No Calender in react mui Datepicker/Calender

Tags: reactjs, calendar, material-ui

[image]

Im  trying to use the mui's onscreen always on Calender component and it says that there is no component here in the pickers folder like that, but I found some answers saying that material ui has an inbuild onscreen Calender ex: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375422/the-material-ui-datepicker-can-use-like-component-without-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - refer to [this document](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker) .

Using the code like this variant="static";

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
      disableToolbar
      variant="static"
      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
      margin="normal"
      id="date-picker-inline"
      label="Date picker inline"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      KeyboardButtonProps={{
        "aria-label": "change date",
      }}
    />
```